# Getting error 400 from updating a cell by google sheetsAPI

Tags: node.js, google-sheets-api, google-apis-explorer, bing-ads-api

I am trying to update a cell in a spreadsheet through Google spreadsheet API.

Currently, I'm having the following code snippet:

```
 sheetsApi.spreadsheets.values.update({
      spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId,
      range:"Sheet1!P1",
      valueInputOption:'USER_ENTERED'},
      {"data":{"values":[[5]],
      'majorDimension':"ROWS"}
    }
    )
```

And it gives the following error:

```
{
"error": {
"code": 400,
"message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"data\" at 'data': Cannot find field.",
"status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
"details": [
{
"@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
"fieldViolations": [
{
"field": "data",
"description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"data\" at 'data': Cannot find field."
}
]
}
]
}
}
```

Could someone give me some help with this please?

Thank you very much!

Since I am only testing this 'update' function, the script is very simple, as the following:

```
function main() {
        const credentials = {
        accessToken: '',
        clientId: '',
        clientSecret: '',
        refreshToken: ''
          };
        const spreadsheetId = ''
        var sheetsApi = GoogleApis.createSheetsService(credentials);

       sheetsApi.spreadsheets.values.update({
    spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId,
    range: "Sheet1!P1",
    valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED",
    resource: {
      values: [[5]],
      majorDimension: "ROWS"
    }
  }, function(err, result) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err.errors);
    return;
  }
  console.log(result.data);
})
}

var GoogleApis;
(function (GoogleApis) {
  function createSheetsService(credentials) {
    return createService("https://sheets.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v4", credentials);
  }
  GoogleApis.createSheetsService = createSheetsService;

  function createDriveService(credentials) {
    return createService("https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/drive/v3/rest", credentials);
  }
  GoogleApis.createDriveService = createDriveService;

  function createGmailService(credentials) {
    return createService("https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/gmail/v1/rest", credentials);
  }
  GoogleApis.createGmailService = createGmailService;

  // Creation logic based on https://developers.google.com/discovery/v1/using#usage-simple
  function createService(url, credentials) {
    var content = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
    var discovery = JSON.parse(content);
    var baseUrl = discovery['rootUrl'] + discovery['servicePath'];
    var accessToken = getAccessToken(credentials);
    var service = build(discovery, {}, baseUrl, accessToken);
    return service;
  }

  function createNewMethod(method, baseUrl, accessToken) {
    return (urlParams, body) => {
      var urlPath = method.path;
      var queryArguments = [];
      for (var name in urlParams) {
        var paramConfg = method.parameters[name];
        if (!paramConfg) {
          throw `Unexpected url parameter ${name}`;
        }
        switch (paramConfg.location) {
          case 'path':
            urlPath = urlPath.replace('{' + name + '}', urlParams[name]);
            break;
          case 'query':
            queryArguments.push(`${name}=${urlParams[name]}`);
            break;
          default:
            throw `Unknown location ${paramConfg.location} for url parameter ${name}`;
        }
      }
      var url = baseUrl + urlPath;
      if (queryArguments.length > 0) {
        url += '?' + queryArguments.join('&');
      }
      var httpResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { contentType: 'application/json', method: method.httpMethod, payload: JSON.stringify(body), headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}` }, muteHttpExceptions: true });
      var responseContent = httpResponse.getContentText();
      var responseCode = httpResponse.getResponseCode();
      var parsedResult;
      try {
        parsedResult = JSON.parse(responseContent);
      } catch (e) {
        parsedResult = false;
      }
      var response = new Response(parsedResult, responseContent, responseCode);
      if (responseCode >= 200 && responseCode <= 299) {
        return response;
      }
      throw response;
    }
  }

  function Response(result, body, status) {
    this.result = result;
    this.body = body;
    this.status = status;
  }
  Response.prototype.toString = function () {
    return this.body;
  }

  function build(discovery, collection, baseUrl, accessToken) {
    for (var name in discovery.resources) {
      var resource = discovery.resources[name];
      collection[name] = build(resource, {}, baseUrl, accessToken);
    }
    for (var name in discovery.methods) {
      var method = discovery.methods[name];
      collection[name] = createNewMethod(method, baseUrl, accessToken);
    }
    return collection;
  }

  function getAccessToken(credentials) {
    if (credentials.accessToken) {
      return credentials.accessToken;
    }
    var tokenResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token', { method: 'post', contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', muteHttpExceptions: true, payload: { client_id: credentials.clientId, client_secret: credentials.clientSecret, refresh_token: credentials.refreshToken, grant_type: 'refresh_token' } });    
    var responseCode = tokenResponse.getResponseCode(); 
    var responseText = tokenResponse.getContentText(); 
    if (responseCode >= 200 && responseCode <= 299) {
      var accessToken = JSON.parse(responseText)['access_token'];
      return accessToken;
    }    
    throw responseText;  
  }
})(GoogleApis || (GoogleApis = {}));

// Base64 implementation from https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/master/lib/msal-core/src/Utils.ts
class Base64 {
  static encode(input) {
    const keyStr = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";
    let output = "";
    let chr1, chr2, chr3, enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4;
    var i = 0;
    input = this.utf8Encode(input);
    while (i < input.length) {
      chr1 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
      chr2 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
      chr3 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
      enc1 = chr1 >> 2;
      enc2 = ((chr1 & 3) << 4) | (chr2 >> 4);
      enc3 = ((chr2 & 15) << 2) | (chr3 >> 6);
      enc4 = chr3 & 63;
      if (isNaN(chr2)) {
        enc3 = enc4 = 64;
      }
      else if (isNaN(chr3)) {
        enc4 = 64;
      }
      output = output + keyStr.charAt(enc1) + keyStr.charAt(enc2) + keyStr.charAt(enc3) + keyStr.charAt(enc4);
    }
    return output.replace(/\+/g, "-").replace(/\//g, "_").replace(/=+$/, "");
  }
  static utf8Encode(input) {
    input = input.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n");
    var utftext = "";
    for (var n = 0; n < input.length; n++) {
      var c = input.charCodeAt(n);
      if (c < 128) {
        utftext += String.fromCharCode(c);
      }
      else if ((c > 127) && (c < 2048)) {
        utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 6) | 192);
        utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
      }
      else {
        utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 12) | 224);
        utftext += String.fromCharCode(((c >> 6) & 63) | 128);
        utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
      }
    }
    return utftext;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my answer. From your script in your question, I had thought that "You want to put 5 to the cell "P1" of "Sheet1" using Sheets API with googleapis of Node.js.", although you had not added the tags related to the language. And also from your replying, you had not mentioned whether my understanding is correct. So I had thought that my understanding was correct. But from your latest reply, I noticed that my understanding had been not correct. So I have to remove my answer. I apologize for my poor skill.

Comment: And could you please add your tags related to the language you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Insert values like this

```
row.range = "Sheet1!"+"A"+(i+2)+":M"+(i+2)
row.values = [
   [....],
   [....],
   [....],
   [....],
   [....],
   [....],
]
```